# I want to boot ubuntu but i dont know how to add the ext4 partition to my boot menu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

So , i used UNetBootin to install Ubuntu 18.04 on my pc , i installed it on a parititon i created from my hard drive

[the partition ( shows empty , but i used ext2read to explore it and ubuntu is installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7JRK.png)

i opened the installer i think it was something like Ubuntu 18.04 Installer it was on the desktop i partitioned the drive on the partition i created 100 gbs i set it to ext4 then installed told me to restart now i dont know how to get into it

What do i do then ! Thanks

EDIT : Dual boot : I have windows 10

[the partition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDb5X.png)

Comment: Did the installer spend about 20-40 minutes installing Ubuntu after partitioning? Or did it tell you to reboot immediately after partitioning?

Comment: i waited 15-20 minutes

Comment: What does your "boot menu" look like? Are you booting into Windows? Into GRUB? Or something else?

Comment: into windows , i can only choose Windows 10 and UNetBootin

Comment: If you choose UNetBootin, it simply offers to install Ubuntu again?

Comment: yes , ill try to go into unetbootin menu wait

Comment: Looks like you made a common new-user mistake: You tried to skip a step of the install instructions. Start over, and follow all the steps this time. (Hint: The installer won't overwrite itself...so you either need a USB stick or DVD...or yet another partition)

Comment: If you install ubuntu successfully , it should install grub and put the appropriate MBR into your disk to enable you to see the grub menu at system startup. So I think the grub isn't installed correctly so you cannot see the linux boot-menu

Comment: **DANGER DANGER** Don't use ext2read as it WILL corrupt your Ubuntu partition.